# Rendering elements of array fetched with React does not work

Tags: reactjs

I'm successfully fetching an array of objects from a local ethereum blockchain (successful as in, I've logged the data in `componentDidMount` and it is what its supposed to be). Its a dynamically sized array
(`inventory`), so I gotta fetch it element by element. Here are the relevant parts:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({fetching: true}, () => {
      this.loadData()
        .then(result => this.setState({fetching: false}))
    })
  }

  async loadData() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      const netId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

      this.setState({account: accounts[0]})

      if(typeof accounts[0] !== 'undefined'){
        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0])
        this.setState({balance: balance})
      }
      else {
        window.alert('Please login with MetaMask')
      }

      try {
        const plotRepository = new web3.eth.Contract(PlotRepository.abi, PlotRepository.networks[netId].address)
        const plot = await plotRepository.methods.claimPlot(this.state.account).send({from: this.state.account})
        this.setState({plot: new web3.eth.Contract(Plot.abi, _plot.plot)})
        const size = await this.state.plot.methods.size().call()
        const tiles = await this.state.plot.methods.getTiles().call()
        await this.loadInventory() // this is where I'm loading the array in question
        this.setState({size: size})
        this.setState({tiles: tiles})
        // logging the array here works
      } catch (e) {
        window.alert(e)
      }

    } else {
      window.alert('Please install MetaMask')
    }
  }

  async loadInventory() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inventoryinfo)) {
      const item = await this.state.plot.methods.getInventoryItem(key).call()
      this.setState({inventory: [...this.state.inventory, {
        name: key,
        value: parseInt(item[0][1]),
        count: item[1]
      }]})
    }
  }
```

Again, logging the array in the fetching functions works just fine. I'm also using a flag (`fetching`) which denotes whether all data has been successfully loaded or not, and I only try to render data once everything is loaded:

```
  render() {
    const { plot, account, fetching, tiles, inventory } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Currently logged in with account: { this.state.account }</p>
        <p>Balance: { this.state.balance } </p>

        { fetching ? // make sure things are fetched before rendering them
           <p>Loading</p> :
           <div>
             <UserPlot tileData={tiles} plot={plot} account={account}/>
             {
               inventory[0].name // inventory[0] is undefined 
                                 // inventory.length is not
             }

           </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Trying to display any element of the array gives me an undefined error. Rendering the array length works though (`{inventory.length}`). This is weird since I'm doing the same thing with another array that I'm fetching and displaying in the `UserPlot` component and that works just fine (only difference is that in this case the array is static and I can load it all in one go but I don't think that has anything to do with it)

Comment: when you log `inventory` inside render, what do you get?

Comment: and what is `inventoryinfo` ?

Comment: @RedBaron `inventoryinfo` is an array of strings which represent all the inventory element names I want to query. Logging `inventory` shows the elements of the array, which I've checked multiple times to be correct as they're the default values set in the contract.